# Как забрать данные из элемента?

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

Добрый день.

Есть генерируемая страница, на ней - к примеру, 50 кнопок:

```
<a data-toggle="n1" href="1" id="button" class="c1">Ответить 1</a>
<a data-toggle="n2" href="2" id="button" class="c2">Ответить 2</a>
и т.д.
```

Как вызвать эвент при нажатии на это все, я знаю, но после нажатия я должен открыть форму, дать юзеру заполнить её и отправить аяксом на сервер. Но как мне в эвент передать идентификатор кнопки, чтобы отличать их друг от друга? Возможно, есть специальный тег, значение из которого можно забрать?

Вот при нажатии на `id="button"` срабатывает эвент, а как мне забрать значение из data-toggle href class или любого другого спец. тега, чтобы понять, что нажали именно на 2-ю, и работать нужно со 2-й записью в бд.

Спасибо.

Comment: @barseon, вы классы задали разные, а ID у всех элементов одинаковый? )) У вас **должно быть** с точностью наоборот. 

**В пределах одной страницы не может быть два и более элементов с одинаковыми атрибутами ID.**

Эту фразу возьмите в рамочку, повесьте на видное место и повторяйте каждый день, как мантру ;)

Comment: имя id, например, button, должно встречаться на странице только один раз, 2 и более раз одинаковых id ведут к ошибкам, посмотрите пример @xfloooo как JS ведёт себя при обращении по одинаковому id: http://jsfiddle.net/m4d97z8k/1/

Comment: Да, извините, это я наспех накидал, ctrl+c ctrl+v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать this - http://jsfiddle.net/m4d97z8k/

HTML

```
<a data-toggle="n1" href="1" id="button" class="c1">Ответить 1</a>
<a data-toggle="n2" href="2" id="button" class="c2">Ответить 2</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('data-toggle'))
    return false
})
```